# Check the date of the regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I use the regular expression.

```
validates :cc_exp_date , format: { with: /(?<month>1[0-2]|0[1-9])\/(?<year>[0-9]{2,4}$)/, message: "invalid date" }
```

Use this expression to check the date in this format:

```
MM/YY, MM/YYYY.
```

But when I enter a date like this:

```
MM/YYYYYY
```

Validation fails and the value is saved in the database. What did I do wrong?

Comment: don't you think we might need some more code to tell you what could be wrong ? if data is saved while validation fails, then it's most probably you're testing the validation result wrongly.

Comment: Not directly what you are asking, but note that the regex as stated would accept MM/YYY formatted values.

Comment: have you tried removing the names from the regex? check with `with: /1[0-2]|0[1-9]\/[0-9]{2,4}$/`

Comment: in the end, I did so.
`/^(?<month>1[0-2]|0[1-9])\/(?<year>[2-9]\d[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d)$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct regular expression.

```
validates :cc_exp_date , format: { with: /\A(?<month>1[0-2]|0[1-9])\/(?<year>[2-9]\d[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d)\z/, message: "invalid date" }
```